# insert many image and other data into database and get insert last id with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have a problem with insert last id. when sending image data to the models, I've been able. but when they merge with insert_id () me trouble here.

my view :

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('produk_adm/proses_tambah_produk');?>
      <div class="col-md-6 input group">
        <label>Product Name :</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" required>
        <br>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 input group">
        <label>Image :</label> <i style="color:red;">*max 1 MB</i>
        <input type="file" name="image" class="form-control" id="gambar">
        <br>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 input group">
        <label>Point :</label>
        <input type="number" name="point" class="form-control" id="point" value="0" required>
        <br>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 input group">
        <label>Additional images :</label> <i style="color:red;">*max 1 MB</i>
        <input type="file" name="add[]" class="form-control" id="gambar">
        <br>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 input group">
        <label>Additional images :</label> <i style="color:red;">*max 1 MB</i>
        <input type="file" name="add[]" class="form-control" id="gambar">
        <br>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 input group">
        <label>Additional images :</label> <i style="color:red;">*max 1 MB</i>
        <input type="file" name="add[]" class="form-control" id="gambar">
        <br>
      </div>
     <?php echo form_close();?>
```

my controller :

```
function proses_tambah_produk(){
    $config['upload_path']          = 'assets/img/produk';
    $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
    $config['max_size']             = 1000;
    $config['overwrite']             = TRUE;
    //$config['max_width']            = 1024;
    //$config['max_height']           = 768;
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    $files = $_FILES;
    $count = count($_FILES['add']['name']);
    for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++)
            {
            $_FILES['add']['name']= $files['add']['name'][$i];
            $_FILES['add']['type']= $files['add']['type'][$i];
            $_FILES['add']['tmp_name']= $files['add']['tmp_name'][$i];
            $_FILES['add']['error']= $files['add']['error'][$i];
            $_FILES['add']['size']= $files['add']['size'][$i];
            $this->upload->do_upload('add');
            $upload_data = $this->upload->data();
            $name_array[] = $upload_data['file_name'];
            $fileName = $upload_data['file_name'];
            $images[] = $fileName;

            $result = $files['add']['name'][$i];

            //print_r($result);
            }



    $target = $this->input->post('nama');
        if($this->input->post()){

                $this->upload->do_upload('image');
                $imagex = $_FILES['image']['name'];
                $data = $this->input->post();
                $data['nama_depan'] = $this->data['nama_depan'];

                $this->produk_adm->add($data, $imagex, $result);

                log_helper("product", "adding Product ".$target."");
                redirect('trueaccon2194/produk');
            }else{
                log_helper("product", "failed");
                redirect('trueaccon2194/produk/tambah_produk');
            }
}
```

and my models :

```
function add($data, $imagex, $result){

    $data_produk = array(
        'nama_produk'   => $data['nama'],
        'slug'          => $data['slug'],
        'milik'         => $data['miliknya'],
        'jenis'         => $data['jenisnya'],
        'artikel'       => $data['artikel'],
        'merk'          => $data['merknya'],
        'keterangan'    => $data['editor1'],
        'tags'          => $data['tags'],
        'kategori'      => $data['kategori'],
        'parent'        => $data['parent'],
        'harga_retail'  => $data['retail'] - ($data['diskon'] / 100 * $data['retail']),
        'harga_odv'     => $data['odv'],
        'harga_net'     => $data['retail'] - ($data['diskon'] / 100 * $data['retail']),
        'diskon'        => $data['diskon'],
        'stok'          => $data['stok'],
        'berat'         => $data['berat'],
        'gambar'        => $imagex,
        'point'         => $data['point'],
        'status'        => $data['aktif'],
        'dibuat'        => $data['nama_depan'],
        'tgl_dibuat'    => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    );
    $this->db->insert('produk', $data_produk);

// MY PROBLEM HERE //
    $last_insert_id = $this->db->insert_id();
    $count = count($result);
    for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++){
        $results = array(
            'id_product' => $last_insert_id,
            'image_product' => $result[$i],
            );
$this->db->insert('product_image_additional', $results);return $this->db->insert_id();
        //print_r($results);
    }

}
```

how to get multiple image name and put into array and insert_id() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one input needed.

```
<input type="file" name="add[]" class="form-control" id="">
```

thats return array of files.

```
 $count = count($_FILES['add']['name']);
    for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++)
            {enter code here
            }
```

it's correct.

you can use

```
$result=array();
$result_image_name=array();
```

after every insert to database

```
$result[]=$this->db->insert_id()
```

then return $result array

```
$uploaded=$this->upload->do_upload('add');
 $result_image_name[]=$uploaded['file_name'];
```

I hope this solution worked!